# How many topologies exist on a finite set?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

In my topology class we are asked to list all topologies on a $3$ element set. I have found $29$ and this should be the correct result. Now I wonder whether there is some formula that determines this number exactely or at least whether there are better bounds than $2$ and $2^{2^n}$ ;)

Comment: [This article discuss your problem](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2313548?uid=3738016&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106572704863)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence is [OEIS A000798](http://oeis.org/A000798).  Your $29$ is correct.  It begins

$1, 1, 4, 29, 355, 6942, 209527, 9535241, 642779354, 63260289423, 8977053873043, 1816846038736192, 519355571065774021, 207881393656668953041, 115617051977054267807460, 88736269118586244492485121, 93411113411710039565210494095, 134137950093337880672321868725846, 261492535743634374805066126901117203$

and a formula in terms of the number of partial orders and Stirling numbers is given.

Comment: Exam exercise one: Write down all topologies on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ ;)